# Is it possible to fetch WikiData by given random pageId?

Tags: javascript, api, cors

I'm trying to write a simple Wikipedia Search App with included 'Feel Lucky' button.
Is it possible to send request for Wikidata by given pageid? Just like below:

```
async function luckySearch(){
    cleanResults();
    try{
        let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000 + 1);
        let endpoint = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&formatversion=2&pageid=${random}`;
        let response = await fetch(endpoint,{
            method:'GET',
            headers:{
                accept:'application/json',
            },
            type:'cors',
        });
        if(!response.ok){
            throw new Error(`Error! status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        else{
            let json = await response.json();
        }
    }
    catch(err){
    console.log(err.message);
    }
}
```

and always throws 'Failed to Fetch'. Frankly, I'm not sure if either request is wrong, or CORS does not allow to fetch without origin set up. Can somebody explain that to me slowly with mercy, please?

I've changed properties of endpoint to make sure that request has right method. I've checked as well if API contains any action that replies to pageid of Wikipedia article

Comment: Just add `origin=*` to the url parameters and it should work. Keep in mind thought that not all of your random values will exist as `id`. `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?origin=*&action=parse&...`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right: it's a CORS error : the browser does not let you access remote data on Wikipedia server because the server did not mark the request as safe for your domain. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is missing, as explained in [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin).

You should explicitly ask the wikipedia server to add this header using the `origin` parameter (see [mediawiki API doc](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Cross-site_requests#CORS_usage) for details).

Changing your `endpoint` to this should work :

```js
let endpoint = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&origin=*&formatversion=2&pageid=${random}`;
```

Comment: Thank you for all details! It works like should, however, referreing to API doc and MDN article, setting origin to * (so..using wildcard to allow all site to access to private API is not the best idea). I know it's not an issue since wiki API is publicly available, but let me know if I understand it well. In this case, to protect API, shall I set the origin parameter into string which contains and adress of requesting domain? Sorry if question is silly - newbie on board :)

Comment: It's not a silly question (I've asked it to myself as well). I tried to set the domain instead of a wildcard, but mediawiki API does not support this. You could allow only selected domain if you were the wikipedia server admin, as explained in the doc.